# 3D Beam in XNA 4.0

Tags: 3d, xna, textures, xna-4.0

I was looking for a way to create a 3D beam effect in XNA 4.0. Currently, I am casting a ray and drawing it so I have the essentials, but I just need the graphics.

I am looking for something similar to what this person is asking:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46912/how-to-make-a-3d-beam-effect-with-xna-4-0

I have had a look at the link which was posted as a reply to this question:

http://www.catalinzima.com/samples/lightning-sample/

However the implementation is only for 2D, and I require it be to rendered in 3D. I tried to use this in my project but the textures sometimes doesn't render at certain angles. I have looked at billboarding, but I think that because the source of the beam is close to the camera, and the destination is far away, the texture will be stretched quite a lot. As for using billboarding for the above example, I have no idea where to start or how that will work.

I'm a bit confused as to how I should go about this, and it would be great if someone could give me some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a laser beam in 3d space by billboarding a 2d texture such that the texture's normal was always coplanar to a vector going from gun To Camera & another that goes in the direction the laser gun was pointing. It was very easy. I made a short video on how it was done:

http://www.screencast.com/t/LDzD2NXOZ

Answer (score 1):

The way I would tackle the problem is to render one or more cylinders from the beam source to the beam target with series of stretched "leopard print" style textures (that rotate / move during the beam's firing) and blur applied to give it a soft edge.

How one achieves all of that really depends on whether one is planning to use the High Def or Reach profile.

Comment: I am using the High Def profile, it is meant for PC and I am also using the Sunburn framework. Is it possible to stretch cylinders? Would the blur be applied using the XNA/Sunburn framework or otherwise?

Comment: If you're not constructing the cylinders programatically and thus can't specificy the cylinder length (i.e. you're using a mesh) then the easiest way to stretch a mesh is by scaling it when you render it. (i.e. use a ScaleTransform)I haven't checked but it wouldn't surprise me if someone has already written a blur component for the Sunburn engine.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your help. I'll try constructing them programmatically and see how I get on.